# Execute Package Task - Is there a way to bind the Child Package parameter to a constant?

Tags: ssis

I want to execute a package multiple times, each time using a different value for the Child package parameter.

Is there anyway to do it?

I could create a variable to hold the value and use an Expression Task to update it after each package execution but I'd like to avoid it if possible.

The desired outcome would be:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I carried it out the following way:
I've loaded all these values to a record set.
Then Iterated on this record set using for each sequence container.
Finally, called the package in the sequence container and assigned the value to the package parameter.

Answer (score 1):

*Execute Package Task* requires that child package parameters should be bound to variables only, no constant values.

You could create a string variable with desired value, and map it at *Execute Package Task*. Child package does not alter variables of the Parent package (unless you do some tricks), and the variable will be kept intact.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use a system variable instead of constant and user dummy variable:

> System::TaskName

and give a name "Patient" to your Execute Package Task.

In this case you do not have to pollute your parent package with variables but also can reuse the same approach for other child packages